# I write JSON to SQLite, but err: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'itervalues'?

Tags: python, json, sqlite

```
# Description: write JSON to SQLite
# Date Modified: 10/22/13
# write JSON to SQLite

import sqlite3
import requests
import json

sqlite_name = 'poloniex_125.db' 
FILE_NAME = 'historical.csv'
FILE_NAME_JSON = 'json.csv'
test_list=[]



def sqlite_get_data_from_json():

    traffic = json.load(open(FILE_NAME_JSON))
    db = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_name)
    query = "insert into medicoes values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    columns = ['globalTradeID', 'tradeID', 'date', 'type', 'rate', 'amount','total']
    for timestamp, data in traffic.iteritems():
        keys = (timestamp,) + tuple(data[c] for c in columns)
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute(query, keys)
        c.close()



def get_json_from_polo():


    url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTradeHistory&currencyPair=BTC_NXT'

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)


    if r.status_code != 400:
        with open(FILE_NAME_JSON, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r:
                f.write(chunk)
        print('get_json_from_polo    2')
        return True




sqlite_get_data_from_json()
```

but err:    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'itervalues'  .

why and how to do ?

i want to get data from poloniex.com.   i am beginner for python.
thank you help me....

i want to get data from poloniex.com.   i am beginner for python.
thank you help me....

Comment: The JSON seems to have a list (array) as the most outer element. You seem to expect a dictionary (object).

Comment: what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

When you're debugging code it can often be useful to use interactive mode.

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTradeHistory&currencyPair=BTC_NXT'
>>> r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> with open('pFile.json', 'wb') as f:
...     for chunk in r:
...         f.write(chunk)
...         
62
613
965
915
<lines omitted here>
818
704
809
761
632
```

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d pointed out, you can see from examining the first few hundred bytes of the output file produced by this code that it's a list of dictionaries.

```
[{"globalTradeID":76456788,"tradeID":886859,"date":"2017-01-25 17:53:41","type":"sell","rate":"0.00000662","amount":"252.35289868","total":"0.00167057"},{"globalTradeID":76456784,"tradeID":886858,"date":"2017-01-25 17:53:41","type":"sell","rate":"0.00000662","amount":"95.73319613","total":"0.00063375"},{"globalTradeID":76456782,"tradeID":886857,"date":"2017-01-25
```

You can process this list in a straightforward way without the need for the json library, as follows.

```
>>> with open('pFile.json') as f:
...     allofthem = eval(f.read())
...     for item in allofthem:
...         print (item)
...         
{'total': '0.00167057', 'amount': '252.35289868', 'date': '2017-01-25 17:53:41', 'globalTradeID': 76456788, 'tradeID': 886859, 'rate': '0.00000662', 'type': 'sell'}
{'total': '0.00063375', 'amount': '95.73319613', 'date': '2017-01-25 17:53:41', 'globalTradeID': 76456784, 'tradeID': 886858, 'rate': '0.00000662', 'type': 'sell'}
{'total': '0.00063445', 'amount': '95.83876657', 'date': '2017-01-25 17:53:41', 'globalTradeID': 76456782, 'tradeID': 886857, 'rate': '0.00000662', 'type': 'sell'}
<items omitted>
```

Now all you need to do is to add in the lines to insert these data into the database.

Comment: Now all you need to do is to add in the lines to insert these data into the database.-----------can you give me code about how to do ?   thank you very much.....